# Image Backup size doesn't match size on the card?

Tags: sd-card, image

I'm following [a tutorial](http://sysmatt.blogspot.com/2014/08/backup-restore-customize-and-clone-your.html) about how to make a backup of my Raspberry PI to another SD Card with rsync...

My Raspberry PI has one nginx http server, and a couple of node.js wiki daemons running on it.  The wiki daemons run on startup using an upstart job that points to a shell script which starts the daemon.

The tutorial says to shut these services down.

While following the tutorial, I shut down all the wiki daemons and nginx using `service <service> stop` commands

When I look at my mounted directories where the backup files are copied to,

```
root@raspberrypi:/proc/sys/fs# df -h | grep -e 'newpi\|\/dev\/root\|boot'
/dev/root       6.0G  3.0G  2.7G  53% /
/dev/mmcblk0p5   56M  9.6M   47M  17% /boot
/dev/sda2       7.2G  3.0G  3.8G  45% /tmp/newpi
/dev/sda1        60M  9.5M   51M  16% /tmp/newpi/boot
```

`/dev/mmcblk0p5 (/boot)` and `/dev/sda1 (/tmp/newpi/boot)` should be the same size, but they're 0.1 MB off.  yet when I compare the directories with `diff -qr /tmp/newpi/boot /boot` I don't receive any output, indicating that these directories are the same.

Is this just a storage discrepancy between different kinds of SD Cards?

Comment: One way to test if it is just a difference between cards would be to restore the backup and see if everything seems to be working coreectly.

Comment: when you regularly copy files with `rsync`, you may lose a few kilobytes here and there, because the directories do not shrink back after adding and then deleting a lot of files. get rid of `-h`, the actual difference could be 1 byte, or 2 bytes, or 10 bytes, but becomes 0.1M because of the rounding errors.

Comment: Adding to lenik's point, things such as filesystem journaling, block size, and files hidden under mountpoints may affect this.  There are too many ambiguities and possibilities here WRT a ~1% difference to allow for a meaningful answer (also, it's off topic as general linux questions should go to [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: Well the backup worked for what it's worth.  Go ahead and move my question.